# @Schedules spring boot wrong

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have this scheduler:

```
    @Schedules({
            @Scheduled(cron = "0 05 00 * * *"),
            @Scheduled(cron = "0 */90 03-22 * * *")
    })
```

After 3 AM the program runs every hour, not every 90 minutes. Do you know why?

Comment: I recommend you read this documentation article: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use both :-

0 0-21/3 * * *

30 1-22/3 * * *